# React testning library Undefined property in component

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I dont understand why the property of the component is breaking the test?
Do i have to pass the component the properties? Even if i do  pass the props i still get the same error.

I dont want to test implementation details.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
it("render correctly", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<CalendarAvailability />);
    const date = getByTestId("date");

    expect(date).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

The Component:

```
import {Availability, AvailableDate, Status, AvailableDateContainer} from './CalendarAvailability.css'

function CalendarAvailability({unitData}) {
  return(
    <Availability data-testid="calendar-availability-component">
      <AvailableDateContainer>
        <AvailableDate data-testid="date">{unitData.date}</AvailableDate>
      </AvailableDateContainer>
    </Availability>
  )
}

export default CalendarAvailability;
```

The failing test:

```
  ● <CalendarAvailability /> › renders without breaking

TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined

   5 |     <Availability data-testid="calendar-availability-component">
   6 |       <AvailableDateContainer>
>  7 |         <AvailableDate data-testid="date">{unitData.date}</AvailableDate>
     |                                                     ^
   8 |       </AvailableDateContainer>
  9 |     </Availability>
```

I dont want to test the props only the rendring of the div?

Comment: Where does `unitData` come from?

Comment: Its a prop that the component recieve

Comment: Can you try to pass a mocked date for the component like `render(<CalendarAvailability date={mockedDate} />)`?

Comment: How do i test conditional rendering in component? the content of the component only renders i has unitData